# Mismatched types in if let statement: found Option expected Result

Tags: rust

I am trying to parse a file that has a pipe delimiter between each value and each line is a new record. I am iterating over each line like this:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let source_file = File::open("input.txt").unwrap();
    let reader = BufReader::new(source_file);
    for line in reader.lines() {
        if let Some(channel_line) = line {
            println!("yay");
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=80b1a9c8a94f1c6665c353015661a016&version=stable)

However, I get an error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:9:20
  |
9 |             if let Some(channel_line) = line {
  |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum    `std::result::Result`, found enum `std::option::Option`
  |
  = note: expected type `std::result::Result<std::string::String, std::io::Error>`
  = note:    found type `std::option::Option<_>`
```

This error is confusing to me as the found type is what I expected namely `Option<Result<String, Error>>` as indicated by the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Lines.html#method.next) so it would make sense to unwrap the `Option` before the result assuming I am not missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You linked to the documentation of `next`, but you're not using `next` (not directly anyway), you're using a for loop. In a for loop the type of the iteration variable (i.e. the type of `line` in your code) is the `Item` type of the iterator, which in your case is `Result<String>`.

The type of `next` is `Option<Item>` because you might call `next` on an iterator that already reached the end. The body of a for loop won't ever execute after the end of the iteration, so there's no point in the iteration variable being an option.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I was under the incorrect belief that the for loop was directly  leveraging the next function.

Comment: @rpiper *the for loop was directly leveraging the `next` function* — yes, it does use `next` internally. It handles the case of `Some` or `None` for you, executing the body when `Some` and exiting the loop on `None`.

Comment: @rpiper It is, but it's more along the lines of "If next returned Some(x) assign `x` to the loop variable, else end the loop".